# Prediction intervals for a Poisson count (in R)

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, prediction-interval

Is there a convenient way in R to calculate a [probability prediction interval](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/secure/v8n3/preston.cfm#Section2)
for a count sampled from Poisson($\lambda$), for known lambda? That is, for a given
$\alpha$, find $a$ and $b$ such that $P(a\le X\le b)\ge1-\alpha$,
where $X\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$. Is there a generic way to do this
in R for any of its built-in distributions?

Comment: What other constraints, if any, do you want to put on this problem? Otherwise, it seems `qpois(1-alpha, lambda)` satisfies the requirements.

Comment: An two-tailed alternative might be `c(qpois(alpha/2, lambda),qpois(1-alpha/2, lambda))`

Comment: @cardinal (and @Henry) It's not that simple, because in effect $\lambda$ must be estimated.  Suppose that $Y\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda n)$ (the "count sampled from Poisson$(\lambda)$") and, independently, $X\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$; let $F$ denote their *joint* distribution.  The prediction interval is a pair of functions $a(Y)$ and $b(Y)$ such that $\Pr_F(a(Y)\le X\le b(Y))=1-\alpha$ (with some slack in the inequality allowed for the discrete nature of $X$ and $Y$).

Comment: @whuber - I agree with your interpretation of "prediction interval", but then the rest of the question should be modified to reflect that.  The second sentence matches what cardinal and Henry answered.

Comment: @Karl I inserted a reference and added the adjective "statistical" to make the distinction.  Praneeth, you are more than welcome to improve upon this.

Comment: @whuber: To be honest, I (purposefully) ignored the terminology given the explicit statement later in the question, deeming the former likely to just be an imprecision. Perhaps that was a misjudgment on my part. :)

Comment: @cardinal I agree that the question does state what the prediction interval is, but the notation could be misinterpreted as (a) assume we *know* $\lambda$ or (b) find $\Pr[a\le X\le b\ |\ Y]$

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was not aware of the qpois() function. I intended it to be a probability prediction interval (i.e. lambda known). My actual problem is more complicated: I model $\lambda$ using a GAM (using the mgcv package). I may post this as another question.